# Passing parent query column value into subquery

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I'm building a query that performs to fetch users prize data. I'm trying to get all prize data in one column via group_concat function.

I've almost done with the query, but one thing I'm unable to do is to pass the parent query user id value into subquery to fetch data accordingly.

```
+----+---------------+------------+------------------------------+
|id  |user_email     |user_name   | prizes                       |
+----+---------------+------------+------------------------------+
|1   |user_email     |user_name   | user1 prizes                 |
|2   |user_email     |user_name   | user2 prizes                 |
|3   |user_email     |user_name   | user3 prizes                 |
|4   |user_email     |user_name   | user4 prizes                 |
|5   |user_email     |user_name   | user5 prizes                 |
|6   |user_email     |user_name   | user6 prizes                 |
|7   |user_email     |user_name   | user7 prizes                 |
|8   |user_email     |user_name   | user8 prizes                 |
+----+---------------+------------+------------------------------+
```

Here is the code:

```
SELECT u.ID,u.user_email,u.user_name,
(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( concatval ORDER BY id DESC SEPARATOR  '|~prize~|~sprt~|' )

FROM (

SELECT s.user_id,s.id, CONCAT_WS('|~value~|~sprt~|', s.id,s.offer, IFNULL(p.post_title,'N/A'), s.time, IFNULL(s.expiry_date,'N/A'), IFNULL(m.meta_value,'N/A'), IFNULL(a.meta_value,'N/A'),s.coupon) as concatval
FROM s_data s
LEFT JOIN sc_posts p ON s.campaign_id = p.ID
LEFT JOIN sc_postmeta m ON s.campaign_id = m.post_id AND m.meta_key = 'phone'
LEFT JOIN sc_postmeta a ON s.campaign_id = a.post_id AND a.meta_key = 'address'
WHERE s.user_id = 2 AND s.status = 'awarded' AND (STR_TO_DATE(s.expiry_date,'%M %d,%Y') > DATE(NOW()) OR s.expiry_date IS NULL OR s.expiry_date = '' )
ORDER BY s.id DESC LIMIT 0,7

    ) tmptable
GROUP BY user_id

) as prizes

FROM sc_users u

GROUP BY u.ID
```

I need to pass the u.id of 1st line to line 11 where it says(WHERE s.user_id = 2) to fetch data accordingly. I tried to use this, but it says "Unknown column 'u.ID' in 'where clause'". Can someone help me please. Thanks in advance.

Comment: no its not possible your inner query is executed first and then the top query will get the data with the select as you have it now.

Answer (score 0):

Ypu can add the subquery in the FROM section and JOIN with users
Like this

```
SELECT u.ID,u.user_email,u.user_name,
 prizes.concatval

FROM sc_users u 
  JOIN (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( concatval ORDER BY id DESC SEPARATOR  '|~prize~|~sprt~|' )

FROM (

SELECT s.user_id,s.id, CONCAT_WS('|~value~|~sprt~|', s.id,s.offer, IFNULL(p.post_title,'N/A'), s.time, IFNULL(s.expiry_date,'N/A'), IFNULL(m.meta_value,'N/A'), IFNULL(a.meta_value,'N/A'),s.coupon) as concatval
FROM s_data s
LEFT JOIN sc_posts p ON s.campaign_id = p.ID
LEFT JOIN sc_postmeta m ON s.campaign_id = m.post_id AND m.meta_key = 'phone'
LEFT JOIN sc_postmeta a ON s.campaign_id = a.post_id AND a.meta_key = 'address'
WHERE s.user_id = 2 AND s.status = 'awarded' AND (STR_TO_DATE(s.expiry_date,'%M %d,%Y') > DATE(NOW()) OR s.expiry_date IS NULL OR s.expiry_date = '' )
ORDER BY s.id DESC LIMIT 0,7

    ) tmptable
GROUP BY user_id

) prizes on.prizes.user_id=u.ID

GROUP BY u.ID
```